# Can you send packets on Mac OS using Python?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, scapy, packet

I am trying to broadcast packets from my Mac OS running the latest version using scapy. I have another computer sniffing for the packets I send. I make the packet a Deauthenication packet because not many travel over a network, making it much easier to sift through the data to determine if it is the packet I was trying to send out.

here is my packet: `RadioTap(ChannelFrequency=2412)/Dot11(type=8, subtype=12, addr1='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', addr2='94:6a:77:e9:c5:b2', addr3='94:6a:77:e9:c5:b2')/Dot11Deauth(reason=7)`

Which would make this packet very easy to identify. Then, I send it using scapy with this line of code: `sendp(packet, iface='en0', count=100)`

If I were to use this instead, `sendp(packet, iface='en0', count=100, monitor=True)` then the computer completely crashes and restarts. That is why I put the interface in a monitor mode anyways.

Back to my original issue, the packet simply doesn't show up on a device that sniffs, and will pick up other deauthentication packets that go across the network, but not the ones I am trying to send out. That is how I know mine aren't sent. Also, yes the program is run with `sudo`, yes the interface is in monitor mode (I have tried with and without), and yes I made sure the sniffer and the sender are both on the same exact frequency/channel. I even specify the channel frequency within the packet, as packets with that exact same frequency have been picked up by the sniffer.

I am beginning to wonder if it is scapy that has the problem sending the packet, or in this case because of the packet format, broadcasting. Or, if it is just because I am on a Mac OS. If there is any way to send a packet using python (any method) please let me know.

I am also on the newest version of Mac OS 10.15.7

If the device can ping by sending packets, shouldn't I be able to send my own specified packets?

Comment: What version of MAC OS are you using ? It changes a LOT between versions

Comment: Just updated it